# Is it considered possible to win a modern Presidential election on a (monetary) shoestring?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, campaigning

The Republican candidate for President currently has a lead in the polls. On the other hand, the Republican party has much less money than the Democrats, eight months before the election. Of course, "anything " could happen between now and then.

Is it considered possible for a major modern U.S. political party to run a "budget" campaign, perhaps running a Harry Truman-style "whistle-stop" campaign or leveraging "free media?"

Or is the conventional wisdom that an underfunded party will get "buried" over the airwaves or caught out with a weaker "ground" operation?

Comment: If it was Mitt Romney or Bob Dole or running the R ticket that might've been true. We're in a different era now. It's going to be another gonzo mudslinging campaign season. What matters is who can capture Tik-Tok, Insta, and Xwitter.

Comment: Evidence/precedent rather says no, but this is the kind of Q that's veering into opinion-based, IMHO.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat: I'm not asking for people's opinions. I'm seeking a "political science"  explanation. That's why I worded the questions "Is it considered possible...?" or "is the conventional wisdom...?" Someone can talk about the media, free or otherwise, but I want an answer (in this example) that will cite studies that demonstrate the impact of such media.

Comment: And how (i.e. on what basis) would political science answer this question?

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat: In marketing, for instance, you make profits by introducing a mix a product, pricing, advertising, selling, etc. I'm pretty sure that politics works in somewhat the same way, except that the parameters, and the "science" is a bit different (but I don't know how). And in marketing, at least, there are theories about how much you can compensate for e.g. weak advertising by a strong product or a low price.

Comment: Theories (like cross elasticity) do not provide an answer for what the empirical values are.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat maybe there's a paper out there looking at the correlation between campaign money spent and votes received?

Comment: If you look at non-Presidential campaigns, there are numerous examples of big money losing.  Former Mayor Mike Bloomberg spent $1 billion dollars in the 2020 Democratic Presidential Primary for example.

Comment: With Trump involved, anything is possible. He's already done lots of things that are more or less unprecedented (from winning with no previous political experience, to persistently disputing the result of an election long after any legal challenge had expired, as well as ignoring scandals that would have felled almost any other politician). Although we live in unpredictable times in other ways, such as shenanigans over Supreme Court appointees and the Republicans' unseating their own House speaker.

Comment: "is the conventional wisdom..." Is this an invitation to speculate who will win the next US presidential election? You could ask for historical data maybe. Like how often has the better financially supported candidate won against the candidate leading in polls half a year before the election or so.

Answer (score 2):

My smartass answer is yes, it is possible, given that you could win a presidential race without even running a modern campaign in the first place.

**Step One: Faithless electors**

Only the Electoral College actually votes for president. Individual voters vote for a presidential slate, and then states appoint a numbers of electors who are pledged to support the candidate the majority of their voters picked.

In some states, its illegal for electors to break that pledge. But in other states it's possible to be a "faithless elector," essentially breaking your pledge to cast a protest vote. In 2016 you had a record number of faithless electors, with ten votes going to folks like Bernie Sanders, Ron Paul, Colin Powell, etc.

In practice, those votes have never swung an election... but what if they did?

**Step Two: No majority!**

Under the 12th Amendment, Congress meets to count the electoral votes. If one candidate has a majority, they become president. But if NO candidate has a majority:

> ...if no person have such majority, then **from the persons having the
> highest numbers not exceeding three on the list of those voted for as
> President**, the House of Representatives shall choose immediately, by
> ballot, the President. But in choosing the President, the votes shall
> be taken by states, the representation from each state having one
> vote; a quorum for this purpose shall consist of a member or members
> from two-thirds of the states, and a majority of all the states shall
> be necessary to a choice.

So essentially, if you have a scenario where the Democrat has 269 electoral votes, the Republican has 268, and there was a protest vote for Weird Al Yankovic, there will now be a vote in the House to pick the president. And their *only* possible choices are those three people.

**Step Three: Shenanigans**

The House has decided presidential elections before, and their resolution has always involved, ahem, shenanigans. In 1824, Andrew Jackson received the most electoral votes, but John Quincy Adams won when Henry Clay's supporters backed him instead... and Clay was then appointed Secretary of State. In 1876 there were widespread irregularities that led to competing electoral slates that would have decided the election, so Democrats and Republicans made a blatant quid pro quo: Democrats would certify Rutherford B. Hayes' election, but the Republicans had to end Reconstruction in the South.

Imagine that the vote in the House is deadlocked. Suddenly, Weird Al lays out his politics, and he's a moderate. Side A realizes that their candidate is a lost cause, but Weird Al is still better for their policies than Side B. He makes a big promise to some states, he promises an appointment or two to another state. Shenanigans.

The deadlock breaks. Al Yankovic ascends to the presidency. America gets weird.

As a postscript, this is all assuming a faithless elector route. But it's certainly possible that an underfunded but high profile candidate could win only one state, and ascend to the presidency under similar scenarios. Ed McMullin for example got more than 20% of the vote in Utah in 2016 with virtually no budget at all. Could a candidate with the profile of a Mitt Romney have won the state entirely by spending a relative pittance? Hey, why not!

Comment: Weird Al for Prez? I'm in!